# Watermark over images with specific font

Tags: watermark, xwatermark

I follow the suggest solution to [place a watermark over images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118987/48642). This works very well. But for my doc I have specified a different main font namely

`\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}`

But somehow this is ignored by the package `xwatermark`[image]

while for the package `background` it works fine [image]

The angle and the position I can play around and handle by myself. But is there an *easy* solution available to use the set mainfonts **and** draw over images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, you are using LuaTeX, right? But xwatermark needs a "NFSS family name" (where "NFSS" stands for New Font Selection Scheme), see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288461/4736

So we get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\newfontfamily\verbatimfont[NFSSFamily=myverbatimfont]{Arial}

\newwatermark*[allpages,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0,fontfamily=myverbatimfont]{DRAFT}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image: xwatermark example]

Comment: Thx for the hint. I'm confused because NFSS font name could be any kind of font or just specific ones? Because your example shows it with Àrialˋ I wonder if it could be ˋLinux Libertine 0ˋas well. Is it a matter that a definition is missing or is it due to the fonts internal specification? If it is the first one - I could define any font, right? If it is the second option than where to find a list of available fonts?

Comment: @LeO I'm not sure what you ask. You can take the name of any font which is installed on your system. Why not Libertine?

Comment: Ahh, ok... I wasn't sure if there is a limitation to (the name of) the font. Especially since you mentioned the NFSS feature. But now its clear - I just need to define it. Thx