# XWatermark - performance issues

Tags: watermark

I want to have on each page a watermark which covers as well images. After solving a [problem with the font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/495772/48642) I tried it now on one of my test documents.

My document has about 220 pgs, with several addtional packages. I need to compile it twice due to ToC. I am using LuaTeX 1.0.4 on a Linux machine. The duration for two pass compile is about 84 sec!!!

When I use the simple `background` package I have about 24 secs!!! (But doesn't cover images.)

I would guess the major diff between 84 sec and 24 sec is due to the usage of the `ltxkeys` package. Most likely it requires some additional runs.

I wouldn't have expected that watermarks causes that kind of speed penalty - if I want to place it over images. Are there other solutions available without that speed problem? E.g. options in `xwatermark`, `ltxkeys`, redefinition of command, different package or perhaps Luacode...

Comment: I wouldn't use xwatermark. It uses the catoptions package and lots of special code which makes it very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use eso-pic to setup watermarks (screenshot compiled with lualatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages,xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\AtPageCenter{\rotatebox{45}{\makebox[0pt]{\fontsize{3cm}{3cm}\bfseries\textcolor{red}{DRAFT}}}}}

\begin{document}
\includepdf{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With the combination of the package `transparent` it works great! Thx.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness at the beginning of this year: `eso-pic` is automatically loaded with `pdfpages`. So there is no need to load it.

Comment: @LeO I know, but you can't write an answer  "use eso-pic" and then hide its loading in a package needed only for the example. That is not very pedagogical.

Comment: Uhhh... I see now... For the `\includepdf` you need the `pdfpages` for the watermarks itself only the `eso-pic` is required. Thanx for your mother take care.