# How to page center adjustbox and rotate?

Tags: watermark

I have a followup question to the previously [provided answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496140/48642). Since my text is NOT fixed and might change dynamically I have problems to center the watermark in the middle of the page

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages,xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{transparent} % used in watermark
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{
    \AtPageCenter{
    {
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{55}{
            \adjustbox{cfbox=red {\fboxrule} 5mm, width=28cm, min height=2cm, max height=2cm}
            {\transparent{0.3}\fontsize{3cm}{3cm}\bfseries\textcolor{red}{
                    %DRAFT%
                    Automatischer Text%
            }}
        }
    }
}
}
\begin{document}
\kant
\end{document}
```

end up with something like
[image]

I know I use some `\put` to adjust the rotated box but this is dependent on the length of the text. Basically I want to have the center of the rotated in the middle of the page. Various attempts of using  `\AtPageCenter`, `\AtPageLowerLeft` failed as well to specify the origin of the `\rotatebox`. The angle of 55° fits well for a A4 paper.

Any hints how to solve it?

BTW: Using `lualatex 1.16`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\AtPageCenter` places the left edge there, not the whole box.  You can use `\makebox` to **really** center it.  Also, remember that any line which ends with a brace adds a space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages,xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{transparent} % used in watermark
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{
    \AtPageCenter{%
    {%
        \makebox[0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{55}{
            \adjustbox{cfbox=red {\fboxrule} 5mm, width=28cm, min height=2cm, max height=2cm}
            {\transparent{0.3}\fontsize{3cm}{3cm}\bfseries\textcolor{red}{
                    %DRAFT%
                    Automatischer Text%
            }}%
        }}%
    }%
}
}
\begin{document}
\kant
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx for providing a full example. This works :-)

Comment: Another way is the package "background".

Comment: I've linked my previous question as well. I have suffered quite some performance issue and found this solution upon recommendation. But I have to confess - I didn't run performance measurements with `background` at the time - especially since I found this solution. Would be interesting to see what difference it has nowadays.